# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot, grub, uefi

First off let me say that I am somewhat inexperienced in using Linux, I do know the basics though. I currently run Windows 10 on my Acer Aspire E 15. For working with ROS kinetic I have to setup Ubuntu 16.04 on my Laptop. I downloaded the Ubuntu ISO and made a 8GB USB-stick bootable using LiLi USB creator (and win32 disk imager just to make sure the stick was indeed bootable). I made a new partition for Ubuntu (~100 GB) and installed Ubuntu from the stick. It told me it finished without problems; I restarted my Notebook and no matter what I do, it keeps booting up Windows. I tried several strategies to solve up this problem, like the boot-repair tool or chrooting into the system to overwrite boot priorities, but it just won't work. What else can I try to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10?

Comment: Is windows booting in efi mode or bios mode? Both os's need to be installed to the same mode

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

When Ubuntu was installed, a second boot manager (GRUB) should have been installed. From what you are describing, it would appear that the default Windows Boot Manager is being used instead of GRUB. I would try the steps suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664002/boot-straight-into-windows-no-grub):

> 1. Boot to Windows.
> 2. Open an *Administrator* Command Prompt window by right-clicking the Command Prompt icon and selecting the option to run it as
>      Administrator
> 3. Verify the existence of the Ubuntu boot manager: `dir \EFI\ubuntu` and make sure you can see "shimx64.efi"
> 4. Type `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`
> 5. Reboot
> 6. If you boot into Ubuntu but GRUB did not give you a menu or if that menu did not include Windows, type `sudo update-grub` in a Terminal

Comment: When running dir \EFI\ubuntu it tells me it can't find the file.

Comment: when running step 4 it tells me it succeeded though, reboot still resulted in Windows.